# How to show a default SVG Fill Color on jQuery mouseout / mouseleave?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I'm in troubles trying to animate SVG figures with jQuery.

What I need in CSS looks like this:

```
svg rect:hover {
  fill: blue;
  transition: .15s;
}
```

Need it in jQuery because I want the 'fill' to be a random color instead of 'blue'. My problem is how to remove the random color on mouseout/mouseleave and show the SVG rect default color. All I can do is to pick another color, purple in the example...

```
$("svg").find("rect").hover(function(){
  var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 150) + ','
                   + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 150) + ','
                   + (Math.floor((256-199)*Math.random()) + 150) + ')';
  $(this).attr("fill", hue);
});
$("svg").find("rect").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).attr("fill", "purple");
});
```

What I got:
http://codepen.io/pixelius/pen/NbyPzK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom `data-*` attributes are officially supported in the current draft of SVG2:

> RESOLUTION: "We will reserve "data-*" attributes to be used in SVG
>   content.

**Source:** *http://www.w3.org/2015/01/15-svg-minutes.html#item03*

This means you can create an attribute `data-fill` for each `rect` and store the original `fill` color in `data-fill` during your `mouseover` event - and then retrieve the same value from `data-fill` during your `mouseout` event.

**Working Example:**

*(N.B. I have used javascript because I am still only in the early stages of learning jQuery)*

```js
var r = (Math.floor((256-199) * Math.random()) + 150);
var g = (Math.floor((256-199) * Math.random()) + 150);
var b = (Math.floor((256-199) * Math.random()) + 150);
var hue = 'rgb('+ r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';

function fillRandom() {
    var originalFillColor = this.getAttribute('fill');
    this.setAttribute('data-fill', originalFillColor);
    this.setAttribute('fill', hue);
}

function fillOriginal() {
    var originalFillColor = this.getAttribute('data-fill');
    this.setAttribute('fill', originalFillColor);
}

var svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');

for (var i = 0; i < svgs.length; i++) {
    var svg = svgs[i];
    var rects = svg.getElementsByTagName('rect');

    for (var j = 0; j < rects.length; j++) {
        var rect = rects[j];
        rect.addEventListener('mouseover',fillRandom,false);
        rect.addEventListener('mouseout',fillOriginal,false);
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color : #031F34;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 6rem;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

svg rect {
transition: all .3s linear;
}
```

```html
<a>
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="38px" height="38px" viewbox="0 0 38 38" enable-background="new 0 0 38 38" xml:space="preserve">
        <rect fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect y="13" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect y="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="13" fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="13" y="13" fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="13" y="26" fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="26" y="13" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="26" y="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
      </svg>
    </a>

<a>
      <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="64px" height="38px" viewbox="0 0 64 38" enable-background="new 0 0 64 38" xml:space="preserve">
        <rect fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect y="13" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect y="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="13" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="13" y="13" fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="13" y="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="26" y="13" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="26" y="26" fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="39" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="39" y="13" fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="39" y="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="52" fill="#2c845f" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="52" y="13" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
        <rect x="52" y="26" fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />
      </svg>
    </a>
```

Comment: Really helpful.

I've added manually a data-fill attribute:

<rect fill="#01121E" data-fill="#01121E" width="12" height="12" />

And this for javascript:

$("svg").find("rect").mouseout(function(){
    var dataFill = this.getAttribute('data-fill');
    this.setAttribute('fill', dataFill);
});

Thank you so much, problem solved.